# Pin the calculator open

Tags: windows

can i find a way to pin a window open while I work around it? For example a calculator

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep a particular application "always on top"

Comment: Your question is vague and it's hard for us to understand what you are trying to tell us. Could you please improve what you mean by "pinning" the application and [providing some context](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)? Thank you... :-)

Comment: You cannot do this without the aid of additional software installed on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

One app:

> [DeskPins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html) can be used to make any application topmost, that is, to keep it above all other windows. Just grab a pin from the DeskPins icon in the system notification area (a.k.a. taskbar tray) and click on any window. This functionality is identical to the "Always on Top" setting found in some programs. With DeskPins you can add this feature to any program!

Another app:

> [PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) is a small application I wrote back in 1998 that some extra menu items to the windows control menu in addition to the standard "Close", "Maximize", etc options. The extra menus are: Always On Top, Transparency and Minimize To Tray.